# File structure: Cascade accessing sub-modules or sub-files by using index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, directory-structure, file-structure

```
modules/
   |
   |--- index.js
   |
   |--- module1.js
   |
   └--- module2/
           |
           |--- index.js
           |
           |--- component1.js
           |
           └--- component2.js
```

Using the structure above, I can access `module1.js` by using the following code;

```
var modules = require('./modules') // or import modules from './modules'
console.log(modules.module1)
```

However I cannot access to `component1` by the following code;

```
var modules = require('./modules') // or import modules from './modules'
console.log(modules.module2.component1)
```

When trying the code, the system throws `Cannot read property 'component1' of undefined` error. So, module2\index.js is not installed.

Is there any chance to access `component1` and `component2` by using `modules` definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit

I guess ES7 ***await*** method overcome this issue with a using like the following;

```
var modules = await require('./modules')
console.log(modules.module2.component1)
```

#### Original answer

The problem is that; Javascript codes work asynchronous.

At the first level is not a problem when defining to a variable. But at the second level needs some time to get and load the module from the depth.

Waiting to load the modules and then defining the components is nonsense in particularly when working on another Javascript platform like React-Native or one else platform which has been built on Javascript language.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will have to do the following in the index files throughout.

modules/index.js

```
module.exports = {
    module1: require('./module1'),
    module2: require('./module2')
}
```

modules/module2/index.js

```
module.exports = {
    component1: require('./component1'),
    component2: require('./component2')
}
```

Comment: Actually, I did what you wrote the above with a bit different way. I use `export  { module1, module2 }`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi @user3765109 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Actually I've considered on your answer. But I thought it's not a certain answer for my question. I've explained the solution the below. Don't delete  your answer. If someone uses your solution, s/he increases the reputation of the answer. Have a nice day...